# Remove all but last entry by column

Tags: sql-server

I would like to  select distinct NAME and delete rows where the ID <> Max(ID) for that NAME.

The table is as follows ...

```
NAME                    DATE                    ID
BudgetX.dbo.Persons 2015-02-13 13:53:38.780 1
BudgetX.dbo.Persons 2015-02-13 13:53:38.780 2
BudgetX.dbo.ILFS        2015-02-13 14:29:55.347 3
BudgetX.dbo.ILFS        2015-02-13 14:29:55.347 4
BudgetX.dbo.ILFS        2015-02-13 14:30:10.813 5
```

I would like to remove all but rows 2 and 5.

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks, RR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a CTE + `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT Name, Date, ID,
          RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID DESC)
   FROM dbo.TableName
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```